# Highlighting parent nav item when child links are showing

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, parent

So, I am working on navigation, which looks like:

```css
#head .nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#head .nav img {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}
#head .nav ul {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#head .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 70px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#head .nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
}
#head .nav > ul > li > a:hover,
#head .nav > ul > li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 231, 208, 0.5);
}
#head .nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#head .nav li.current_page_item a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 231, 208, 0.5);
    color: #ffe7d0;
}
#head .nav ul.children li {
    padding: 0;
}
#head .nav ul.children li a {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #191a22;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 20px 20px 18px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
#head .nav ul.children li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
#head .nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    left: -50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
#head .nav ul li:hover > ul,
#head .nav ul li ul:hover,
#head .nav ul li ul:focus {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href=""><img src="https://url.com/images/logo.png" title="" alt=""></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-7 current_page_item"><a href="https://url.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="https://url.com/about/">About</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="https://url.com/media/">Media</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="https://url.com/music/">Music</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="https://url.com/shows/">Shows</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-23 page_item_has_children"><a href="https://url.com/shop/">Shop</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="page_item page-item-24"><a href="https://url.com/shop/cart/">Cart</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href="https://url.com/shop/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-26"><a href="https://url.com/shop/my-account/">My account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="https://url.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is highlight the parent when the child menu is displayed...like this:

[image]

[image]

I was thinking some JS might be needed here, I tried:

```
#head .nav > ul > li.page_item_has_children > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 231, 208, 0.5);
}
```

Which just puts the `border-bottom` on the Shows link all the time, whether the child `ul` is showing or not, is there a way to add the `border-bottom` only if `#head .nav ul.children li a` is showing?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: We can access css from parent to child not vice versa. So you just use JS to add one class when opening the Child. Then write the css to the added class. It will work.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started over and finally got everything working, no JS needed!

The code didn't change, here is the updates CSS:

```
#head .nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#head .nav img {
    height: auto;
    padding: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#head .nav ul {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#head .nav li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#head .nav > ul {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#head .nav > ul > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}
#head .nav > ul > li:hover > a,
#head .nav > ul > li.current_page_item > a,
#head .nav > ul > li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
}
#head .nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#head .nav ul li ul {
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 200px;
}
#head .nav ul li:hover ul,
#head .nav ul li ul:hover,
#head .nav ul li ul:focus {
    display: block;
}
#head .nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
#head .nav ul li ul li a {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #5d6896;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 20px 20px 18px;
    
}
#head .nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #191a22;
}
```

The one that actually solved my problem:

```
#head .nav > ul > li:hover > a
```

It works much better now, I like how it turned out, hope this helps someone else!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.dropbtn').removeClass('dropbtn-active');
    $(this).find('.dropbtn').addClass('dropbtn-active')
  });

})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
.dropbtn {
  height: 30px;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}
.dropbtn-active {
  background-color: #31b0d5;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:black;
  cursor:pointer;
}
li ,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #31b0d5;
}
.dropbtn:hover{
 color:black;
cursor:pointer;
}

.dropdown a{
text-decoration:none;
}

.dropdown a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

.dropdown:active .dropbtn {
  background-color: #31b0d5;
}
a.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e8f3f4;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #d8dee2
}
.dropdown-content a:visited .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e8f3f4;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="menubar" class=" collapse navbar-collapse row">
    <ul id="dropdownNavbar" class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Home
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span> About
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Media
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Music
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span> Shows
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Shop
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Cart</a>
          <a href="#">Checkout</a>
          <a href="#">My Account</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropbtn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Contact
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This may help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: This one doesn't seem to highlight the parent link either, I was able to find a solution though, thank you for sharing!